# How to figure out if a point is inside the bounds of a rotated rectangle

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems, rotations

I'm trying to figure out an approach (or a formula) to determine if a point (x,y) is inside the bounds of a rotated rectangle.

[image: rotated rectangle graphic]

For this test we can assume that the rectangle is centered on the axis, has a width of w and a height of h, and an angle of θ.  I need a test to see if a point (A or B in the graphic) are inside the rectangle or not.  In the graphic A is not and B is.

The actual goal though is to constrain a point to stay inside the rectangle.

I'm not a straight up mathematician.. I'm a software guy. So I deal with math all the time but  I often come up with a coding approach to solve a problem.

One idea I have for an approach here is this: When the box isn't rotated it's a simple bounds test..

```
if B.x > w/2 then B.x=w/2
if B.x < -w/2 then B.x=-w/2
if B.y > h/2 then B.y=w/2
if B.y < -h/2 then B.y=-w/2
```

So I could rotate B (around the center of the rectangle) by -θ which essentially rotates the 'world' so that the rectangle isn't rotated.  Basically move things into an unrotated space.  Then do the above simple tests on the modified B.  Then after bounding it inside the rectangle, rotate the point back by θ to put it back in the original space.

The other idea I had was to do something with vectors.  Consider that B is a vector from the center of the rectangle.  Then shorten the length of the vector (like normalize it) to a length that constrains it inside the rectangle.  That seems more complex because it would require that I calculate the length vector B can be at each rotation.

Any ideas?

Comment: I now see that someone already answered this question over at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54301/determine-whether-or-not-a-point-lies-within-a-rotated-rectangle

Comment: Which is the same answer as my first approach I listed above of rotating the world space to match the rotated rectangle.  If anyone wants to answer using the vector approach that would be cool.  Or I can answer it myself.

Comment: If you already have a subroutine for testing whether two line segments intersect, then a following approach also works. It has the benefit that it works for all closed polygons - not just rectangles. Take a distant point $B'$ outside the polygon (any point will do). Count the number of intersections of line segments $BB'$ and the edges of the polygon. If this number is odd, then $B$ is inside, if even then $B$ is outside. This is because when we move along the segment $BB'$ every crossing changes the in/out status, and $B'$ was known to be outside. This may have numerical instabilities though.

Comment: interesting.. I don't have a routine to test line segments intersecting as of yet.  But that's a good solution for that.  Still not sure how I would bound it in though.